# Laravel eloquent - Is there a way to add Hint before SELECT?

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

With Laravel 5.7, PostgreSQL and pg_hint_plan, I want to write a SQL query like

```
/*+ IndexScan(users) */ SELECT * FROM users WHERE age=10;
```

with eloquent.

---

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE age=10;
```

can be done by

```
User::where('age', '=', '10')->get();
```

but I can't find how to add `/*+ IndexScan(users) */` before `SELECT`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What is the `IndexScan(users)`? a stored procedure?

Comment: Have you tried a `raw` query? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: `IndexScan(users)` of pg_hint_plan forces the SQL query to use the index about 'users' if I understand correctly. I've thought about `DB::raw` but is there a way to insert the hint before `SELECT`?

Comment: A raw expression is the only way.

Comment: Does it mean `DB::select('/*+ IndexScan(users) */ SELECT * FROM users WHERE age=10');`?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the PostgresConnection class and the PostgresGrammar class to add your own logic to the compileSelect method in the PostgresGrammar class.

```
class PostgresConnection extends \Illuminate\Database\PostgresConnection
{
    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Grammar|\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\PostgresGrammar
     */
    protected function getDefaultQueryGrammar()
    {
        return $this->withTablePrefix(new PostgresGrammar());
    }
}
```

```
class PostgresGrammar extends \Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\PostgresGrammar
{
    /**
     * Compile a select query into SQL.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder $query
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function compileSelect(Builder $query)
    {
        $sql = parent::compileSelect($query);
        return '/*+ IndexScan(users) */' . $sql;
    }
}
```

Need to define a service provider class, it is very important to register this service provider before Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class

```
class DatabasePostgresServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * 此外，在 Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class 之前注册此服务提供程序非常重要
     *
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Connection::resolverFor('postgres', function ($connection, $database, $prefix, $config) {
            // Use your own defined PostgresConnection class here.
            return new PostgresConnection($connection, $database, $prefix, $config);
        });
    }
}
```

Configured in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
        // .... 
        DatabasePostgresServiceProvider::class,
        Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```